# Jsonpath: can not get the needed value using expressions

Tags: json, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

This is the example JSON

```
{
  "customerId": 0,
  "authorizedCustomerIds": [
    0
  ],
  "creativeVersionId": 0,
  "description": "string",
  "version": "string",
  "duration": 0,
  "frameRate": 0,
  "previewImage": "string",
  "previewVideo": "string",
  "renderScript": "string",
  "renderScriptType": "string",
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "type": "IMAGE",
      "name": "string1",
      "parentId": 0,
      "presetId": 0,
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": {},
          "type": "ALPHABETIC",
          "producesVideo": true,
          "renderScriptId": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "TEXT",
      "name": "string2",
      "parentId": 0,
      "presetId": 0,
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": {},
          "type": "ALPHABETIC",
          "producesVideo": false,
          "renderScriptId": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "globalElements": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "disabled": true
    }
  ],
  "shots": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "displayOrder": 0,
      "startFrame": 0,
      "duration": 0,
      "thumbnailFrame": 0,
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "disabled": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sizes": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "displayOrder": 0,
      "main": true,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "properties": [
        {
          "templateElementId": 0,
          "propertyName": "string",
          "linked": true,
          "value": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get the element name which type is TEXT and the properties "producesVideo" is false.

I tried this way but it not works

```
$..elements[?(@.type == 'TEXT' && @.properties[?(@.producesVideo == false)])].name
```

Then I need to extract the path with rest assured

```
.extract().path();
```

using `find` or `findAll` conditions

Comment: What implementation are you using? It may be an issue of support for nested queries.  Note that a spec is currently in progress, and as a result, there's no standardization as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using rest assured `find` and `findAll` expressions the jsonpath should be like this:

```
.extract().path("elements.findAll{it.type == 'TEXT' && it.properties.find{it.producesVideo == false}}.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

What JSONPath implementation are you using? For that document and JSONPath expression, some implementations, e.g. [jayway Java](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and [jsoncons C++](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/ref/jsonpath/jsonpath.md), will return the value result

```
[
   "string2"
]
```

or the path result

```
[
   "$['elements'][1]['name']"
]
```

Other implementations, e.g. Goessner Javascript, can't digest a filter expression with a subfilter. Christoph Burgmer's [JSONPath Comparison](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/) covers that case [here](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/results/filter_expression_with_subfilter.html).